# What does the Javascript:OpenID.Signin('example') Does?

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth, openid, connection

I always admired the stackoverflow.com website.

I also, was always curious about what the `Javascript:OpenID.Signin('example')` here, in the login page of the Stackoverflow.com, does.

You see, i would like to implement something similar to my website, and this one is the question that first came in my mind. (I mean provide, separate button for every different connect provider).

Please keep in mind that i am a newbie and i would prefer, if possible, simple answers.

Thank you in advance.

PS. If you are not willing to tell me what the `Javascript:OpenID.Signin('example')` does, could you please tell me how can i achieve the same functionality?

I am totally lost with the OpenId stuff and in any case would not like to mention the OpenID as is, in my website. I am sure it will complicate things for the users of my website too. I would prefer a solution, connect with Google, Facebook etc separate buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you view source on the page your talking about you can see a script tag for an outside file

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sstatic.net/Js/third-party/openid-jquery.js?v=8"></script>`

If you look there, you'll see it contains a global var called `openid` which contains a function called `signin` among other things.

Here's the function body if you're curious

```
signin: function (box_id, onload) {

    var provider = providers[box_id];
    if (!provider) { return; }

    this.highlight(box_id);

    if (box_id == 'openid') {
        $('#openid_input_area').empty();
        this.setOpenIdUrl("");
        $("#openid_identifier").focus();
        return;
    }

    // prompt user for input?
    if (provider['label']) {
        this.useInputBox(provider);
        this.provider_url = provider['url'];
    } else {
        $('.' + box_id).css('cursor', 'wait');

        if (provider['oauth_version']) {
            this.setOAuthInfo(provider['oauth_version'], provider['oauth_server']);
        } else {
            this.setOpenIdUrl(provider['url']);
        }
        this.provider_url = null;
        if (!onload) {
            $('#openid_form').submit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: btw - does anyone know what the get parameter `v=8` does in this context? beats me